# How to draw a two paragraph div onto a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, xhtml, merge

I'm trying to get it where a whole two paragraph div can be drawn onto a canvas. I'm mostly having problems with getting the div on a canvas without having to use all of the canvas tags and draw out every line. I think this is possible, let me know if it isn't. I'm intermediate with Javascript and Php, experienced with HTML, but new to canvas so try to keep it simple.

HTML Code:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/xml; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Quote It!</title>
<link rel = "stylesheet"
      type = "text/css"
  href = "passext.css" />
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "js2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>It's as easy as One...Two...Three!</h1>
<div id = "instructions">
<p style = "text-align:center;">Instructions:</p>
<ol>
<li>Fill out quote and author fields, then press "Create Quote".</li>
<li>Adjust attributes and watch as it updates in real-time!</li>
<li>Click save and it will convert to a versatile image.</li>
</ol>
</div>
<div id = "tips_warnings">
<p style = "text-align:center;">Tips &amp; Warnings:</p>
<ul>
<li>Don't forget to add quotation marks!</li>
<li>Don't forget a dash before the author.</li>
<li>To create a new quote, hit "Reset", and fill out the form.</li>
</ul>
</div>
<form name = "personalize" id = "personalize">
<fieldset class = "person">
  <legend class = "legend">Personalize</legend>
  <p>
<label class = "uinfo">Quote (One you make up or one you know):</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <textarea id = "quote"
    rows = "10"
    cols = "45"></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
<label class = "uinfo">Author:</label>
<input type="text"
      id = "write_author"
  name = "author"
  value = "eg. (-Billy Joe)" 
      onclick = "this.value = ''"/>
  </p>
  <p>
<label class = "uinfo">Text Color:</label>
<select id = "selColor" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value = "#ffffff">White</option>
  <option value = "#000000">Black</option>
  <option value = "#f09dee">Pink</option>
  <option value = "#ff0000">Red</option>
  <option value = "#1e4d0c">Green</option>
  <option value = "#00ff00">Neon Green</option>
  <option value = "#0000ff">Blue</option>
  <option value = "#00ffff">Cyan</option>
  <option value = "#ff00ff">Magenta</option>
  <option value = "#ffff00">Yellow</option>
  <option value = "#cccccc">Grey</option>
</select>
  </p>
  <p>
<label class = "uinfo">Text Style:</label>
<select id = "selStyle" onchange = "myFunction()">
  <option value = "default">None</option>
  <option value = "italic">Italics</option>
  <option value = "underline">Underline</option>
  <option value = "bold">Bold</option>
</select>
  </p>
  <p>
<label class = "uinfo">Background Color:</label>
<select id = "selBack" onchange = "myFunction()">
  <option value = "null">None</option>
  <option value = "#000000">Black</option>
  <option value = "#ff0000">Red</option>
  <option value = "#00ff00">Green</option>
  <option value = "#0000ff">Blue</option>
  <option value = "#00ffff">Cyan</option>
  <option value = "#ff00ff">Magenta</option>
  <option value = "#ffff00">Yellow</option>
  <option value = "#ffffff">White</option>
  <option value = "#cccccc">Grey</option>
</select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label class = "uinfo">Border:</label>
    <select id = "selBorder" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value = "none">None</option>
  <option value = "solid">Solid</option>
  <option value = "double">Double</option>
  <option value = "groove">Groove</option>
  <option value = "ridge">Ridge</option>
  <option value = "inset">Inset</option>
  <option value = "outset">Outset</option>
  <option value = "dashed">Dashed</option>
  <option value = "dotted">Dotted</option>
</select>
  </p>
  <p>
<label class = "uinfo">Border Width:</label>
<select id = "selWidth" onchange = "myFunction()">
  <option value = "500px">Large</option>
  <option value = "375px">Medium</option>
  <option value = "250px">Small</option>
</select>
  </p>
  <p>
<label class = "uinfo">Font:</label>
<select id = "selFont" onchange = "myFunction()">
  <option value = "Times New Roman">Times New Roman</option>
  <option value = "Serif">Serif</option>
      <option value = "Sans-Serif">Sans Serif</option>
  <option value = "Fantasy">Fantasy</option>
  <option value = "Monospace">Monospace</option>
  <option value = "Cursive">Cursive</option>
</select>
  </p>
  <p>
<label class = "uinfo">Font Size:</label>
<select id = "selSize" onchange = "myFunction()">
  <option value = "105%">13pt</option>
  <option value = "120%">14pt</option>
  <option value = "130%">15pt</option>
  <option value = "140%">16pt</option>
      <option value = "150%">18pt</option>
</select>
  </p>
  <p class = "create_quote">
    <input type = "button"
  value = "Create Quote"
  onclick = "myFunction()"/>
  <script type = "text/javascript" src = "js2.js"></script>
    <input type = "reset"/>
  </p>
</fieldset>
</form>
<canvas id = "blank">
  <p id = "blank1"></p>
  <p id = "author"></p>
</canvas>
<input type = "button"
  id = "save"
  value = "Save"
  onclick = "saveFuction()"/>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "js2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript Code:

```
function myFunction(){
var quote, quote1, fsize, fsize1, fColor, fcolor1, bcolor, bcolor1, font, font1, width, width1, border, border1, author, author1, author2, format, fstyle, fstyle1;
format = document.getElementById("blank");
var context = format.getContext("2d");
quote=document.getElementById("quote");
quote1=quote.value;
outPut = document.getElementById("blank1");
if (quote1 != "") {
  outPut.innerHTML = quote1;
} else {
  alert("You need to enter a quote!");
}

author = document.getElementById("write_author");
author1 = author.value;
author2 = document.getElementById("author")
if (author1 == "" || author1 == "eg. (-Billy Joe)") {
  alert("Who wrote this?");
} else {
  author2.innerHTML = author1;
}

fcolor = document.getElementById("selColor");
fcolor1 = fcolor.value;
format.style.color=(fcolor1);

fstyle = document.getElementById("selStyle");
fstyle1 = fstyle.value;
if (fstyle1 == "italic") {
  format.style.fontStyle=("italic");
  format.style.textDecoration=("");
  format.style.fontWeight=("");
} else if (fstyle1 == "underline"){
    format.style.textDecoration=("underline");
    format.style.fontStyle=("");
    format.style.fontWeight=("");
  } else if (fstyle1 == "bold") {
      format.style.fontWeight=("bold");
format.style.textDecoration=("");
format.style.fontStyle = ("");
    } else if (fstyle1 == "default") {
  format.style.fontWeight=("");
  format.style.textDecoration=("");
  format.style.fontStyle = ("");
}

bcolor = document.getElementById("selBack");
bcolor1 = bcolor.value;
format.style.backgroundColor=(bcolor1);

border = document.getElementById("selBorder");
border1 = border.value;
format.style.border=( border1);
if (border1 == "dashed") {
  format.style.borderWidth=("3px");
} else {
  format.style.borderWidth=("5px");
}

width = document.getElementById("selWidth");
width1 = width.value;
format.style.width=(width1);

if (width1 == "375px") {
  document.getElementById("blank").style.position = "absolute";
  document.getElementById("blank").style.left = "962.5px";
}else if (width1 == "250px") {
  document.getElementById("blank").style.position = "absolute";
  document.getElementById("blank").style.left = "1025px";
}else if (width1 == "500px") {
  document.getElementById("blank").style.position = "absolute";
  document.getElementById("blank").style.left = "900px";
}
font = document.getElementById("selFont");
font1 = font.value;
format.style.fontFamily=(font1);

fsize = document.getElementById("selSize");
fsize1 = fsize.value;
format.style.fontSize=(fsize1);
}

function saveFunction(){
  format.location.href = format.toDataURL();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't draw html elements directly on canvas.

You'll have to learn/use the canvas drawing commands.

However, some people have had success with this library that simulates html elements on canvas:

http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

You might also want to know that canvas.toDataURL doesn't allow you to save the image data to a user's local file system for security reasons.

Alternatively,

There are many screen-grabbers out there.  SnagIt is a good one: http://www.techsmith.com/snagit.html

Comment: Okay, well I found [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas). I think this should solve my problem, but I can't get it to work in the first place.

Comment: Yes, that was a well known hack.  Problem is that it's also a security breach so browsers have closed it.  Firefox might still allow it for now--haven't checked recently.  Consider it a dead end.

Comment: are you sure I can't use this somehow? It seems like the perfect solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check out html2Canvas as markE said, it takes a dom element and converts it to a canvas, and then you can draw that canvas onto another canvas something like this:

http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

```
var domElement = document.getElementById('myElementId');
html2canvas(domElement, {
    onrendered: function (domElementCanvas) {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(domElementCanvas, 0, 0, 100, 100);

        // do something with canvas
    }
}
```